# Masonry animation on load

Tags: jquery

Hi i want to get an animation when the item are replaced on the mansonry place when page load, but not when page is resized,

heres my code :

```
  $(function(){
        var blogpost = $('#blogG');

         blogpost.imagesLoaded(function(){
                blogpost.masonry({
                         isAnimated: true,
                        animationOptions: {
                            duration: 750,
                            easing: 'linear',
                            queue: false
                        },
                        itemSelector:'.blogposts',
                        isResizable:true

            });
        }); 
});
```

and my example online : www.mupiz.com/blog/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set `isResizable: false`. It's in the [Masonry docs](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/options.html#isresizable).

Answer (score 0):

I make onload animation next. 1 add class to my blocks in masonry:
    
code css:

```
.box.masonry{
    -webkit-transition-property: left, right, top;
    -moz-transition-property: left, right, top;
    -o-transition-property: left, right, top;
    transition-property: left, right, top;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

And after initialize masonry drop this class from element's be course on browser resize transition works two times.
code js:

```
$('.box.masonry').parent().bind( 'transitionend', function() {
    $('.box.masonry').removeClass('masonry'); 
});
```